# MATLAB R2014a on Ubuntu 12.04 Installation issue (BadMatch. X_PutImage)

Tags: 12.04, macosx, matlab

I am trying to install MATLAB R2014a on Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome. However it says:

```
user@server:~/temp/r2014a$ sudo ./install -v
Preparing installation files ...
->  DVD                 = /home/user/temp/r2014a
->  ARCH                = glnxa64
->  DISPLAY             = :11.0
->  TESTONLY            = 0
->  JRE_LOC             = /tmp/mathworks_26486/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre
->  LD_LIBRARY_PATH     = /tmp/mathworks_26486/bin/glnxa64

Command to run:
/tmp/mathworks_26486/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java -Xmx512m -splash:"/home/user/temp/r2014a/java/splash.png" -Djava.ext.dirs=/tmp/mathworks_26486/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/ext:/tmp/mathworks_26486/java/jar:/tmp/mathworks_26486/java/jar/ja_JP:/tmp/mathworks_26486/java/jar/zh_CN:/tmp/mathworks_26486/java/jar/ko_KR:/tmp/mathworks_26486/java/jarext:/tmp/mathworks_26486/java/jarext/guice:/tmp/mathworks_26486/java/jarext/webservices:/tmp/mathworks_26486/java/jarext/webservices/ws_client_core:/tmp/mathworks_26486/java/jarext/webservices/mcr_dws_client:/tmp/mathworks_26486/java/jarext/axis2 com/mathworks/professionalinstaller/Launcher -root "/home/user/temp/r2014a" -tmpdir "/tmp/mathworks_26486" 

Installing ...
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  72 (X_PutImage)
  Serial number of failed request:  42
  Current serial number in output stream:  46
Finished
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - figured it out after connecting with a different PC.

**Don't use Microsoft Remote Desktop Client (v2.1.1) for OS X.**

See [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2862/whats-a-good-windows-rdp-client-for-mac) for alternative clients.